# What's the difference between mysql-community-server and mysql-community-server-minimal?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I just downloaded the first GA release of MySQL 5.7, and noticed that the RPM bundle comes with two versions of the MySQL server package:

- mysql-community-server-5.7.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
- mysql-community-server-minimal-5.7.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

**What's the difference between the normal and the "minimal" server packages?**

I could not find this information on the MySQL website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `mysql-community-server-5.7.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm` includes the following additional features (list may not included all) that are not available in the `mysql-community-server-minimal-5.7.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`:

- [innochecksum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innochecksum.html)
- [myisam_ftdump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-ftdump.html)
- myisamlog — Display MyISAM Log File Contents
- myisampack — Generate Compressed, Read-Only MyISAM Tables
- mysql_plugin — Configure MySQL Server Plugins
- mysql_secure_installation — Improve MySQL Installation Security
- mysqld_pre_systemd
- mysqldumpslow — Summarize Slow Query Log Files
- perror — Explain Error Codes
- resolve_stack_dump — Resolve Numeric Stack Trace Dump to Symbols
- resolveip — Resolve Host name to IP Address or Vice Versa

I think debugging option is also limited in the `mysql-community-server-minimal-5.7.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm` version.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link for the source of this info?

Comment: No, couldn't find any links. so did the research myself.

Comment: Did you compare the package contents?

Comment: Yes, looked into the structure, config files etc. As the differences are not documented, the best way is to install both the versions on a test server.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal package was designed for use by the official [docker images for MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/).  It cuts out some of the non-essential pieces of MySQL, but is otherwise the same product.